# Scala compiler not infering types in scala:testCompile

Tags: scala, maven, compilation

How can I manage scala-compiler-plugin to compile as in Eclipse ?
src/scala and src/java compile just fine, but when I compile tests, I get

These test run just fine in Eclipse, and I Believe its because of a flag in the compiler eclipse uses.
Anyone with the same issue when trying to compile tests in maven ?

```
[ERROR] MissionDataSet.scala:23: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : com.thegamifiers.fanwards.model.mission.objective.Objective
[INFO]  required: ?{val asInstanceOf: ?}
[INFO] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
```

Comment: Do you mean `src/main/scala` and `src/main/java`? And now you want your tests in `src/test/scala` to run with `mvn test`?

Comment: maybe you can post your code?

Comment: Is this still a problem?